# RPi 3 Wireless Access Point

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi

I've been searching around a lot, and I want to create a Access Point on my RPi 3, but here's the kick... I want to use the integrated wifi in addition to a wifi dongle. So no Ethernet cable at all. All the articles I've found require Ethernet cables...

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/

Follow the link exactly, the step where you configure iptables, replace eth0 with wlan1 when entering the commands into the terminal(whatever your WiFi dongle is named).